# React native webview loses injected data on state change

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, webview

Is there any way to keep injected javascript data in the webview when there are state changes?

I use the injectJavascript prop to enter data into a web view. The data is entered as expected but when the react native state changes the data is lost which probably means the webview is reloaded. Is there any way to keep this data after state changes?

Verified on android device

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this issue?  When i navigate back to page from screen stack, the webview is set to initial state

Answer (score -1):

use `injectJavaScript` method like:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#the-injectjavascript-method